# How to avoid that local declarations hide higher level declarations

Tags: java, scope, naming-conventions

I am reading the Java Code Conventions PDF and I noticed this:

> Avoid local declarations that hide declarations at higher levels. For
>   example, do not declare the same variable name in an inner block:

```
int count;
         ...
         func() {
             if (condition) {
                 int count;
... }
... }
```

It is nothing new and I frequently find myself writing such code. How do you solve such cases? Of course you can say "find a better name", but that is not always easy. Are there any conventions on adding something in front or back of the higher level name?

Comment: *"This is also relevant to methods with parameters (setters etc)"* except that it is standard practice to use the same name in that case and use `this` for the class member that is hidden.

Comment: A good IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse) will show you warnings for that kind of code, especially if you activate tools like FindBugs or CheckStyle

Comment: @assylias:  Not quite so.  My shop prefixes all parameters with `the` to avoid scoping confusions - we always know that `theX` is a parameter being passed in.

Comment: @Makoto By standard I meant that this is an accepted practice that should not surprise anyone. I'm not saying that everybody does it (ps: I don't like `theX` type of variables but it's a matter of taste!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use scope-specific variable naming conventions to reduce confusion.

```
String[] names;

public void populateNames(String[] theNames) {
    names = theNames;
}
```

Also, you can explicitly state which scoped variable you want by use of the `this` keyword.

```
int count = 0;
public void func() {
    int count = 0;
    if (condition) {
        this.count++; // increment the class-scope count variable
    } else {
        count++; // increment the local scope variable
    }
}
```

In general, *just don't reuse your variable names*.  It confuses those that read your code, and makes debugging a bit harder.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about implicitly incremention. Maybe you just saved a hour of my life :)

Comment: using this only make sense in some contexts. Nested if/while etc that is not always possible.

Comment: @Dude:  I'm not sure I follow.  Why would a nested if/while statement break this convention?  Especially, why would you reuse (as in redeclare) a variable in a nested if/while statement when you could put the variable at a higher scope in the method?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'explicitly', or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count;
count = 1;
```

is not the same as

```
int count;
this.count = 1;
```

So if you work with local variable, you just don't user "this."

Answer (score 0):

Top level variables have more "detailed" names that lower ones. For example:

```
class A{

    private int mVegetablesCount;

    public void foo(){
        int count;
        if(true){
           int cnt;
             if(true)
                int c;
        }
    }
}
```

Just as variant. Also, it's good idea to name your class fields specificaly. In my example field named fith prefix "m".

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with *method* variable declarations, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the instance variable as in the following example:

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Here, `this.id` refers to the instance variable, whereas `id` refers to the parameter passed in to the setter.

I know you said that you don't want to hear suggestions of using better variable names, but I do think the only situation you should really have duplicated names are when you're preparing to set a new value for an ivar, or have just read an ivar. Even then, it's often more readable to use names with a bit more meaning, so for example if you only need a variable that is of the same time as `barr` temporarily, name it `tmpBarr` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this coding style used in a library:

- member variables: `_variable`
- local variable: `locVariable`
- methods arguments (parameters): `parVariable`

But I personally think it clutters the code.

Any good IDE will use a colour code that makes a clear difference between a local variable and a class member.